# What does "in function of traffic" mean?

Tags: landing, visual-approaches

I’ve been familiarising myself with circuit procedures hoping to increase my knowledge (I’m not a pilot, but have a great interest in aviation). I have come across the following instructions:

> When the runway is behind the aircraft and in function of nearby
> traffic in the circuit, the pilot must descend to the aerodrome
> circuit altitude in function of traffic and can now join the beginning
> of the downwind leg.

I have no idea what they mean by "in function of traffic." I have looked everywhere but can not find reference to this term. Can anybody help?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume this is from [this site](https://wiki.ivao.aero/en/home/training/documentation/Joining_an_aerodrome_circuit)?  It appears to have been machine-translated from the Dutch, and has a lot of grammar errors.  The term is not standard English or standard aviation terminology.

Comment: Yes, please provide a source for these sort of terminology questions.  Because my first instinct reading it was that it was a poor translation from some other language.  If you are a fluent or native English speaker you should do your learning from reputable publications originally written in English, *(FAA, Jeppeson, etc)*.  If not, study in your native language.

Comment: @mins, that's a reasonable interpretation of a bad translation, and could stand as an answer.

Comment: Tevildo, that is indeed the site that I found the information on.

Answer (score 1):

As the question is based on a poor wording, due to the site, the actual meaning can be different, but here is a possible one, for what it's worth:

> in function of nearby traffic in the circuit, the pilot must descend to the aerodrome circuit altitude in function of traffic

This sentence seems to say the pilot must join the downwind leg from the crosswind leg, avoiding other traffic (also joining the circuit) during the descent, and traffic already in the circuit (in the downwind leg).

[image]

[Source](https://skybrary.aero/articles/aerodrome-traffic-circuit).

Answer (score 1):

According to FAA and ICAO standard phraseology, "in function of traffic" has no meaning, assuming that it was a wrong translation, it seems to be "due Traffic"!